# How do I compute the shortest distance from a point to line segments?

Tags: matlab, math, distance, shortest

I wanna write a neat code to compute the shortest distance between a point and any line segments in any directions. I understand that in many cases the shortest distance would be a line perpendicular from the point to the line segment and in some cases would be the line connecting the point on either ends of the line segment (whichever is smaller).

I have done my research and have written a few codes! The outcomes are not quite right as you may see in the attached image below in which the red line changes in each iteration in terms of it's length and the shortest distance from star to each line is computed in order to get a distribution for the distance . As you see for some of the line segments the shortest distance which is supposed to be perpendicular, is actually not.

The way I coded was to use `d=sqrt((xstar-xline)^2+(ystar-yline)^2)` and then minimize it with respect to `xline` and considering the x-end coordinates of each line segment, get `xline` and `yline` and then connect the star to that point on the line but as it can be seen it does not look right.

Can anyone help like by posting a code or a pseudo code or algorithm?

[image]

**Problem still not solved!**

Please consider the upper left corner line segment in the attached figure:

```
A = [-157.5461    559.9243];
B = [-127.6786    390.5373];
P = [-70          450];
```

and I have used exactly the same algorithm as mentioned in the answers, but still the shortest distance does not seem right as it is not connecting `P` to `B`!

Comment: What I understand of your question is that given a point P and a segment AB you want to calculate the shortest distance between the point P and some point of the segment AB, I am correct, if so, the shortest distance is the Perpendicular to the line containing the segment AB, say PQ, if Q belongs to AB, otherwise the minimum distance will be at either end. What is your specific question?

Comment: Please include the code you have

Comment: The problem you are having with your updated image is related to the relative scaling of your axes. The calculations for the shortest distance are likely correct, but the scaling is greatly compressed on the y axis relative to the x. Modify it with `axis equal` and everything will probably look fine.

Comment: Thanks very much ! I think I can move on now ! I appreciate all of your helps !

Comment: @Reza: Glad to hear it. If one of the answers helped you, please consider marking it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this would be much simpler to solve analytically. Lets walk through an example.

Lets say your line segment is

```
y = x + 4, defined for x such that 3 <= x <= 4
```

and your point is `(6,3)`

The slope of the perpendicular line can easily be found by taking the negative reciprocal of the slope of your line segment, so in this case

```
  y = -x + b
```

To then solve for the appropriate value of `b` such that your line passes through the point, substitute the x and y values of the point.

```
(3) = -(6) + b ==> b = 9
y = -x + 9
```

Now we want to find the point that your perpendicular line and your original line (assuming it is infinitely long, even though it isn't) cross. So we set them equal to each other and solve for x.

```
x + 4 = -x + 9
2x = 5
x = 2.5
```

Therefore they would cross at the point such that `x = 2.5`. We know that your line segment is only defined on `x such that 3 <= x <= 4` though, so you know that the shortest connecting line between your point and initial line is NOT the perpendicular in this case and is instead one of the endpoints. Since `x = 2.5` is less than the domain (the x-values) of your line segment, you know that the endpoint to choose is the one with the lower value of x. Hence, you can just calculate the line that passes through those two points, which it seems you know how to do from what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

### Derivation:

We already know that the shortest distance from a point `P` to an infinite line is given by a perpendicular to the infinite line that runs through `P`. The caveat is that we're dealing with line *segments* along this infinite line, and the perpendicular line crossing may fall outside the segment. Let's start with this definition of three points:

```
P = [xP yP];  % Point coordinates
A = [xA yA];  % Starting point of line segment
B = [xB yB];  % Ending point of line segment
```

Now, let's consider the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between the vectors `AP` and `AB`, and that the [scalar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) of `AP` onto `AB` is equal to `dot(AP, AB)/|AB|`, the dot product of the two vectors divided by the magnitude of `AB`. This is the component of `AP` that lies along vector `AB`, and gives us the point at which we have the shortest distance between `P` and the infinite line running through `A` and `B` (i.e. the perpendicular intersection point). If we divide that component again by the magnitude of `AB` it will give us a parametric value that is 0 at point `A` and 1 at point `B`. A value outside of the range `[0 1]` indicates that the shortest distance occurs outside the line segment, and the closest point to `P` on the line segment will be one of the segment end points.

Now we can put together an algorithm:

```
vec = B-A;                    % Vector from A to B
u = vec*(P-A).'/(vec*vec.');  % Parametric value along AB

if (u <= 0)      % Perpendicular is outside segment, closest to A
  C = A;
elseif (u >= 1)  % Perpendicular is outside segment, closest to B
  C = B;
else             % Closest point is within segment
  C = A+u.*vec;
end
```

And `C` will give you the point along your line segment `AB` that is closest to `P`. Extending this calculation to handling a number of line segments simultaneously in a vectorized manner will require a couple modifications to the above code...

### Vectorized solution:

Let's first define a point and a set of 3 line segments to use for this example:

```
P = [ 1  1];
A = [ 0  0; ...  % Starting points (x, y) of segments
     -3  3; ...
      0  4];
B = [ 2 -2; ...  % Ending points (x, y) of segments
     -1  1; ...
      3  1];
```

Now we'll replicate the rows of `P` to match `A` and `B`, rework the calculations involving `u` to accommodate more than one segment, and convert the parametric checks to indexing operations:

```
P = repmat(P, [size(A, 1) 1]);
vec = B-A;
u = sum(vec.*(P-A), 2)./sum(vec.*vec, 2);
C = A+[u u].*vec;
C(u < 0, :) = A(u < 0, :);
C(u > 1, :) = B(u >1, :);
```

This yields the following result for `C`:

```
C =

     0     0
    -1     1
     2     2
```

And we can visualize it as follows:

```
plot([A(:,1) B(:,1)].', [A(:,2) B(:,2)].', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
hold on;
axis equal;
plot(P(1, 1), P(1, 2), 'bo', 'MarkerSize', 16);
plot([P(:,1) C(:,1)].', [P(:,2) C(:,2)].', 'm--');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys ! The problem is solved now !

Comment: @Reza: Well, what was the problem?

Comment: I tried "user2027202827 's  suggestion and it worked but it takes a long time to run! Then I implemented your idea because it takes much shorter to run but I am not getting the right answer ! I do it  first by calculation of the C = A+u.*vec; for the infinite line and then check if C falls within each line segment or not ! Via another approach I did that separately for each line segments meaning A and B are the end points of line segment and not the infinite line and then use exactly the same algorithm you have proposed but it did not work again. Not giving me the right answer !  Any idea ?

Comment: @Reza: Just saying it didn't work won't help me help you. Give me some numbers you tested or edit your question to include the code you tried that didn't work. It worked for the test cases I tried.

Comment: sure ! Here is the code ! I cant attach the figure here so that u can see but please let me know if the code is understandable or not so that I can clarify

Comment: just edited thank u for your time ! please let me know if any part is not clear!

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help !  I have modified the main question as the problem still persists ! Could u please take a look?